# virtual environment for Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Does other languages like Java or Kotlin has a feature of virtual environment like python does?

I have tried google searches but all the results are for Venv on Python only.

Comment: There are tools like jenv

Comment: A sidenote: In Java there is something called the classpath. Each application has their own classpath from where they can load dependencies. Thus we can say that  the dependencies of an application are somewhat already isolated. There is no global system wide installation of libraries. Therefore, the problem that virtualenv tries to solve is already somewhat solved by the classpath.

Comment: So in summary: You don't need a venv for Java/Kotlin. Which is good, managing python venv is a nuisance at best.

Answer (score 0):

For Java - jenv

For Kotlin - Scoop (and jenv maybe)

Comment: so jenv is.. what, a wrapper around `update-alternatives`?